# Sorting an array by another index array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, d3.js

I'm iterating over array couples and I need to sort one by the order of the other.

Say I have these two arrays:

```
aLinks = [4,5,6]
bLinks = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I need to return:

```
aLinks = [4,5,6]
bLinks = [4,5,6,1,2,3]
```

meaning that i need to have the items that match first array first and than the rest,
sorted by order if possible.

I'm working with d3 so I'm using forEach to go through the link sets and save the order of aLinks.

I don't know how to apply this order to bLinks

```
var linkOrder = [];

linkSets.forEach(function(set, i) {
  linkOrder = [];

  set.aLinks.forEach(function(link,i){
    linkOrder.push(link.path);
  })
});
```

Comment: Post some code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post also a little bit more about your expactations. What should happen if one the items of the first array is not inside the second one or what if the second one contains one of the items of the first one multiple times?

Comment: If the first array is `[6, 5, 4]`, should the second array begin with `[4, 5, 6]` (i.e., sorted) or `[6, 5, 4]` (matching the order in the first array).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like:

1. Take out the matching items from second array into a temp array
2. Sort the temp array
3. Sort the second array containing only items that did not match
4. Concatenate the second array into the temp array

**Code** - *With the fix provided by User: basilikum*

```
var first = [4,5,6];
var second = [1,7,3,4,6,5,6];
var temp = [], i = 0, p = -1;

// numerical comparator
function compare(a, b) { return a - b; }

// take out matching items from second array into a temp array
for(i=0; i<first.length; i++) {
    while ((p = second.indexOf(first[i])) !== -1) {
        temp.push(first[i]);
        second.splice(p, 1);
    }
}

// sort both arrays
temp.sort(compare);
second.sort(compare);

// concat
temp = temp.concat(second);
console.log(temp);
```

**Working Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/kHhFQ/

Comment: Thanks! that also solves that problem of the items from the first array not being sorted in the second.

Comment: If needed: here is an upated version of techfoobar's fiddle that handles multiple occurances in the second array: http://jsfiddle.net/kHhFQ/1/

Comment: @basilikum - Thank you. That's a clean fix. Will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You end up with `A + sort(A-B)` - so you just need to compute the difference between the 2 arrays. Using some [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) convenience methods for example:

```
var A = [4,5,6];
var B = [1,2,3,4,5,6];

var diff = _.difference(A,B);

var result = _.flattern(A, diff.sort());
```

Answer (score 1):

iterate the first array, removing the values from the second array and then appending them to the start of the array to get the right order :

```
var arr1 = [4,5,6];
var arr2 = [1,2,3,4,6,5];

arr1.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b;});

for (i=arr1.length; i--;) {
    arr2.splice(arr2.indexOf(arr1[i]), 1);
    arr2.unshift( arr1[i] );
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/2h3Q8/2/)