# Easy way to sort 2 arrays in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm learning JavaScript and was wondering if there was an easy way to sort 2 lists like the ones here:

```
var names=["item", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"];
var points=[12, 12345, 5765, 123, 3, 567765, 99, 87654, 881, 101];
```

How would I display the items from 'names' according to the corresponding value in 'points'? For example, for the above `item6` would displayed first and `item5` would be displayed last.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be any obvious or intuitive relationship between the two. Please explain in more detail

Comment: Do any of these answer your question?
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/37063224/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/14004188/1048572 https://stackoverflow.com/q/16759404/1048572

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's *easy enough*, but you could make an array of objects, sort it by the `value` prop and just map to get only the `name` props.

```js
let names = ["item", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"],
    points = [12, 12345, 5765, 123, 3, 567765, 99, 87654, 881, 101],
    
    res = names.map((v, i) => ({ name: v, val: points[i] }))
               .sort((a, b) => b.val - a.val)
               .map(v => v.name);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat lengthy solution (with a much more concise version below). The basic idea is to:

1. Sort the `points` array in descending order
2. Loop through the sorted array, and find each value's position in the original `points` array
3. Grab the corresponding item from the `names` array
4. Push the value into a new array

```js
var names=["item", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"];
var points=[12, 12345, 5765, 123, 3, 567765, 99, 87654, 881, 101];

const sortedPoints = points.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a;
});

const sortedNames = [];
sortedPoints.forEach(function(val) {
  const position = points.indexOf(val);
  sortedNames.push(names[position]);
})

console.log(sortedNames)
```

For a more concise solution, following the same process above but taking advantage of some shortcuts:

```js
const names = ["item", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10"];
const points = [12, 12345, 5765, 123, 3, 567765, 99, 87654, 881, 101];

const sortedNames = points.slice().sort((a, b) => b - a).map(val => names[points.indexOf(val)]);

console.log(sortedNames)
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript doesn't have a zip function natively.  But that is most of what you want to do here.  A little utility library like [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#zip) is pretty handy.  You can view the annotated source if you just want to replicate a zip function yourself.

```
var zippedAndSorted = _.zip(names, points)
.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b - a;
});
```

Then you can iterate over each pair:

```
zippedAndSorted.forEach(function(namePoint) {
    console.log('Name: ' + namePoint[0] + ' Points: ' + namePoint[1]);
});
```